# C#4.5のフォームの継承について

Tags: c#, windows, .net

C#の継承について質問です
継承元のフォームで作成した部品が、派生先のフォームでロックがかかってしまい困っています
Form1が継承元としてForm2を派生させました
Form1にはbutton1、Layoutpanelと、その更にLayoutpanel1の上にpanel1を貼り付けています

button1のModifiersプロパティをpublicにしたところ、
ボタンは派生先で動作変更が出来ました
しかし、panleのModifiersプロパティをpublicにしても派生先ではロックがかかっており、
他のパーツの配置が出来ません
また、panelを載せているLayoutpanelもpublicにしたのですがやはりロックがかかりっぱなしでした

試しに、フォーム上にパネルを直接貼付、Modifiersプロパティをpublicとしたところ、派生先でもパネル上にパーツを配置できたので
Layoutpanel→panelとするときだけ、派生先でロックがかかってしまうようですが
デザインの関係上Layoutpanelを外すのは難しいです

Layoutpanel→panelとしたときに、派生先でpanel上にパーツを配置するのには
他に、どのような操作が必要でしょう(Layoutpanelはいじれないようにしたいのですが出来ないようならLayoutpanelの操作は可能になってしまってもいいのですが・・・)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FlowLayoutPanel`その他の.NET Framework 2.0で追加されたコントロールは[ビジュアル継承をサポートしない](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/1z3efhd2.aspx)と明言されています。対応するデザイナー等も非公開クラスですので変更は難しいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。マイクロソフトがそう言ってるのなら諦めるしか無いですね・・・他の方法を考えます